# scroll to bottom of the div doesn't work

Tags: javascript

```
function ereja(){
  var newscrollHeight2 = $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight;
  return newscrollHeight2;
}

var newscrollHeight = ereja();
var oldscrollHeight = $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight;

function merrmesazhet(){
  $('#messages').load(
    "nxirr_mesazhet.php?room=<?php echo urlencode($dhoma24); ?>"
  );     
  setTimeout(ereja, 1000);
  if( newscrollHeight != oldscrollHeight ){ 
    $("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages")[0].scrollHeight); 
  }
}
```

What's wrong with this code? Why it doesn't work? I am trying to scroll to bottom of the div when a user writtes a new message.  Any idea?

Comment: what do you mean unreadable?

Comment: Three scripts blocks, for starters, making your code go everywhere but in a straight line.

Comment: well, it does not work even with one script block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are actually calling `merrmesazhet()` and that you are testing on `IE>=8` as lower versions don't support [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollHeight).  Then your main issue is the use of `setTimeout` which is essentially calling `ereja` every second and doing *nothing*.

Indeed you do not even need the JS timer - you are using jQuery which supports a callback in it's [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function (which executes **once** on a successful load rather than repeatedly). Your if-statement in it's current form will always evaluate to *false* as it isn't within the function executed on the timer anyway.

Something like this may work for you:

```
var oldscrollHeight = $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight;

function merrmesazhet(){
    $('#messages').load(
        'nxirr_mesazhet.php?room=<?php echo urlencode($dhoma24); ?>',
        function(){
            var newscrollHeight = $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight;
            if( newscrollHeight != oldscrollHeight ){
                $("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages")[0].scrollHeight);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BwH5q/)